# How to read the pdf file using jpedal in javafx

Tags: javafx-2, jpedal

I need to read the pdf file using jpedal in javafx.I have tried the jpedal lgpl src provided PdfDecoder class getPageAsImage() but it gives the pdf pages as images.If i do like this then i am not able to perform search operation on pdf file.Is there any other method which reads the pdf file except reading as images.If anyone has an idea regarding this can plz give me the reply.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

did you have a look at the examples: http://www.idrsolutions.com/how-to-extract-text-from-pdf-files/ ?

I can also suggest PdfBox (http://pdfbox.apache.org/) with works great for text extraction from PDF files.

have fun